Looking for supernatural/sci-fi movie from mid/late 80s or early 90s
I can't remember much about this film but I hope somebody knows it.
The only thing I can remember is  the following:
It was American.
There is a small town with a fountain and people are put in this fountain. A guy returns to/visits this town for some reason (I can't remember why). People are sacrificed when they reach a certain age or it is a fountain of youth and they become young again (I can't remember which).
Thats all I can remember. Anyone know what film it is?

I have found the film. I got a few elements wrong in the description but the film is called 'the sring' (2000) if anyone is interested.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

I found the film. Its called 'the spring' if anyone is interested.




You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the details for the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

Was it the fountain of youth, or were people being sacrificed?

Fountain of youth. Well.. it was a stream, not a fountain.

@NapoleonWilson The answer is found by the OP herself, so we can all rest assured.

@poepje "The answer is found by the OP herself, so we can all rest assured." - That's quite irrelevant to the problem, though. A good answer includes sufficient explanations for everyone to see that it is correct. Despite what identification questions might suggest, the questions and answers here are not for the asker alone.

I understand that, but what do you want to prove if the OP already knows it's that movie? No one else will care about 'evidence' if you ask me.

I added link to trailer.. sorry

@poepje "what do you want to prove" - Uh, that the movie fits to the details given in the question, I guess. Are you actually arguing against a clearer and better answer here? - "No one else will care about 'evidence'" - Of course in practice noone will, as noone will care about the question ever, it's an ID question of not particularly high quality. But should that stop us from encouraging proper answers? Or should we just turn our heads away from the question and try to pretend it and its answers just aren't there?

@NapoleonWilson Sorry but I don't get your point. Like I said, this answer is by the same person who asked the question, so I don't see why you have to doubt the answer is right.

@poepje I never said that I doubt the answer is right, I'm not sure why you think that. Of course it's right, but that doesn't make a one-liner without any explanations a good and explanative answer, no matter if it's "right". It's not just about being right, it's also about showing everyone why it's right, that's what makes a good answer apart from one that merely happens to be right by accident.

I thought the point of stackexchange websites is to find the correct answers to questions. I don't understand what other ideals you might have for this site.
